# Сравнение массивов в цикле

Tags: массивы, php, сравнение

Доброго времени суток!

Появился следующий вопрос.

Имеется неопределённое количество массивов (их количество зависит от того, сколько данных введет пользователь). Необходимо сравнить массивы и найти одинаковые значения, которые есть во всех массивах (повторяющееся элементы для всех массивов).

Я попытался использовать функцию `array_intersect` следующим образом:

```
array_intersect (
    for ($j=0;$j<=$kolvo_massiv;$j++) {
        echo $massiv[$j].",";
    }
);
```

К сожалению, данная конструкция не работает.

Может ли кто-нибудь подсказать, как в цикле (или без него) сравнить неопределённое с самого начала любое количество массивов? Если можно, с примером кода.

Comment: @Борис 343, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: @Борис 343, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$massiv` - массив массивов.

Чтобы выяснить общий для *всех* массивов элемент достаточно перебрать только ОДИН массив.

```
$common_elements = array();
$first_massiv = array_pop($massiv);

if (count($massiv) == 0) {
    return $first_massiv;
}

foreach($first_massiv as $value) {
    $element = $value;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($massiv); $i++) {
        if (!in_array($value, $massiv[$j])) {
            $element = false;
        }
        if ($element) {
            $common_elements [] = $element;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Всем спасибо за столь быстрые ответы. Код сверху действительно работает, но обнаружилась в данном коде опечатка.

в строке

if(!in_array($value,$massiv[$j])){

нужно использовать не $j, а $i.

Отдельное спасибо за код пользователю knes.

Comment: а. Да, $i. просто я на ваш код загляделся. @Борис_343, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, можно сделать лучше:

```
$mainArr = array(
  array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
  array(),
);

foreach($mainArr as $k => $arr){
  if(!empty($arr)){
    $intersect = array_intersect($mainArr[0], $arr);  
  }  
}

sort($intersect);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($intersect);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Напишите второй скрипт, который вызывается перед первым получает на вход количество массивов и модифицирует внутри файла первого скрипта вызов array_intersect() и вызывает его. Если слишком много пользователей одновременно обращается к первому скрипту и вы боитесь конфликтов то можно китайским методом сделать 100 разных версий первого скрипта для разного числа массивов и вызывать нужную версию из второго в зависимости от входного параметра.